# Webpack installation issue

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, installation

## **I wanted to setup webpack and babel with npm, but I got this error**

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pdragon":"^0.7.0","to' npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\luchan.vladyslav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-10T10_48_56_298Z-debug.log
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ddd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "components",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  }
}
```

At the begining I have tried to install webpack webpack-dev-server babel-core babel-loader and babel-preset-env in one line. But I got this error, after a while I figured out that problem is related to webpack and wepback-dev-server

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOCkf.png)

Comment: Don't you have an extra trailing comma in your json?

Comment: dferner, no I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you should clean your cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

That will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the corrupt local node_modules is to be blamed. Can you remove the local `node_modules` folder and then freshly install by `npm install' ? That should fix the issue.

Comment: I can't even install nodemon globaly